# Implementing Importer for mail and ftp

Tags: c#, java, php, import, dataimporthandler

Actually i have mail importer which polls the server at specified time interval. But i find one problem in it. Problem is that we need to specify username and password in the URL scheme in plain text , so the problem here is that it's unsecured. So i want anyone to suggest me some way by which this type of insecurity can be removed.

Comment: cant you use SSL? I Asume it is a website you are talking about?

Comment: actually i want to save the messages as a node in  Java content repository

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about what you are trying to do here. Because i'm lost...

Comment: I have an implementation of mail importer which polls a server like gmail at regular interval specified and save the messages as a node in CRXDITE. In this we need to specify username and password in plain text. But now what i want is not to specify password or specify it in encrypted form .